# Forward attachments from multiple messages in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, exchange-server, outlook-2010, outlook-2013

Having a multiple email messages with one or more attachments in each message, how can I forward all such **attachments only** (not the messages, just attachments)? I am looking for a **simple** solution that does not take too much time.

Comment: How are you designing this solution? Via VBA macros, a COM/.NET add-in or an OfficeJS web add-in?

Comment: @EricLegault - I prefer a simple solution using an user interface. Same like **Ctrl+F** forwards selected messages at once, I was hoping there is a trick to forward the attachments only.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Your question would be relevant on superuser.com. And no, there is no way in the UI to forward only the attachments from multiple message into a single forwarded email

Comment: @EricLegault - Just because I said **I prefer**, that doesn't mean I am not open to other ways, including VBA macros and/or solutions. If you have any suggestion that would work on Outlook-2010+, please share your ideas. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in VBA is fairly straightforward.  Use the Explorer.Selection object collection to iterate through the MailItem objects within, and iterate through each MailItem's Attachments collection, using Attachment.SaveAsFile to save each file to disk temporarily.  You can then create a new MailItem object and use MailItem.Attachments.Add to add each of the saved files, then call MailItem.Display to show the email.